# create columns according to row values, loop r

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame like this one:

```
ID  CODE
 1  code_12
 1  code_67
 2  code_76
 3  code_34
```

I would like to put each "CODE" I have on my rows in a column by assigning a 1 for the subjects that have this code in row and 0 otherwise.

When the same subject has several lines (for example subject 1), I would like to repeat the "1" on all its lines, in order to obtain a df like this one:

```
ID  CODE      code_12   code_67  code_76  code_34
 1  code_12   1         1        0        0
 1  code_67   1         1        0        0
 2  code_76   0         0        1        0
 3  code_34   0         0        0        1
```

I managed to do it "code by code" in the way below, but I would like a way to automate this (with a loop or something) if possible as I have a lot of different codes

```
 df$code_12<-ifelse(df$CODE=="12", "1", "0")

 df<-df%>%
  group_by(ID) %>%  mutate(code_12 = max(code_12))



 df$code_67<-ifelse(df$CODE== "67", "1", "0")

 df<-df%>%
   group_by(ID) %>%  mutate(code_67 = max(code_67))
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr`, you can use `pivot_wider` with a value column set to 1

```
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = CODE) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0) )) %>% 
  right_join(df, by = "ID") %>% 
  relocate(CODE, .after = ID)
```

Output

```
> df
# A tibble: 4 x 6
     ID CODE    code_12 code_67 code_76 code_34
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 code_12       1       1       0       0
2     1 code_67       1       1       0       0
3     2 code_76       0       0       1       0
4     3 code_34       0       0       0       1
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work unfortunately... and I don't understand it duplicated all my columns and added rows, I had 1981 and now I have 7489

Comment: That's because you're applying my code to a different dataframe, with more columns probably. Try to read `?pivot_wider` to understand how it works and how to call it correctly on your dataframe. For example you might need additional arguments such as `id_cols = ID, values_from = value`... The `right_join` will also need to be adapted (I used it to keep the original ID column). Without your dataframe, it's difficult to say what you need.

Comment: I will try to look at the functions in more detail to understand what is going on, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `table` + `crossprod`

```
> with(df, cbind(df, crossprod(table(df))[CODE, CODE]))
        ID    CODE code_12 code_67 code_76 code_34
code_12  1 code_12       1       1       0       0
code_67  1 code_67       1       1       0       0
code_76  2 code_76       0       0       1       0
code_34  3 code_34       0       0       0       1
```

Comment: I get this error message : Error in crossprod(table(df))[CODE, CODE] : no 'dimnames' attribute for the array

Comment: @lM__3 Could you use `dput(df)` to share your data in your post?

Comment: I have a big df I don't really know how to share it ...